# How would I parse this XML String?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML string like this:

```
<Summary>Foo</Summary><Description>Bar</Description>
```

I want to read this into a class object:

```
class Foobar()
{
    string Summary {get;set;}
    string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I tried using XmlTextReader, but it throws an exception that no root element was found. This is what I tried:

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(comment)))
{
     while (reader.Read())
     //do something here
}
```

I also tried deserializing it directly into an object like this:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute]    
    public class Foobar
    {

        [XmlElementAttribute("Summary")]
        public string Summary { get; set; }

        [XmlElementAttribute("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }        

    }
```

This fails as well because I cannot define a `[XmlRootElement]` for the class Foobar, since there is no root element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a root element

```
<root>
    <Summary>Foo</Summary>
    <Description>Bar</Desciption>
</root>
```

Comment: What if that isn't an option? If absolutely required, I could do it, but I would prefer not requiring a root element

Comment: You will always need to have a root element or else how can you parse and run query. Also, how will your code understand where to start and where to end.

Comment: Alright, nevermind. I buckled under and added a root element. Thanks for the heads up. Will accept in 5min

Comment: If that is not an option you DO NOTH AVE VALID XML. Ups. Looks QUITE similar to XML, but is not.

Comment: Well, it should always be an option, since you can feed in the root element's tags. Still, while you don't have a valid XML document, you do have a well-formed XML fragment, and `XmlTextReader` can be constructed such that it accepts XML fragments, so root elements most certainly aren't required.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set root element for that your xaml would be

```
<root>
<Summary>Foo</Summary><Description>Bar</Description> 
</root>
```

For Rootelement in XMLSeralizatoion : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to manually add a root element.

```
string xml = "<root>" + comment + "</root>";
```

Then you can parse it with whichever method you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor form that allows for XMLFragments (chunks of XML that could be valid if put into a single element, but which are not so-rooted):

```
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(comment, XmlNodeType.Element, null))
{
     while (reader.Read())
     //do something here
}
```

Better yet, use `Create()`, which gives more flexibility still.